# DatabasePath Registry Entry Not Working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dns, windows-registry, tcpip, hosts-file

I’ve set the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DatabasePath` registry entry in Windows XP and it works as expected; the system loads and uses the HOSTS file in the directory I’ve pointed it to.

However, in Windows 7, it seems to ignore the entry, but I can find no information relating that it is not supported and/or an alternative way to relocate the HOSTS file in Windows 7. I have confirmed that it is still using the default path (`%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc`) by renaming `HOSTS` to disable it, and renaming it back to re-enable it.

(Yes, I have made sure the directory is correct, made sure it does not include the filename, and made sure that the datatype is correct.(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the word from the people at [Windows Client TechCenter > Windows 7 IT Pro Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/ac9710ff-ed68-40c5-b95a-bc8a84600a9d):

> After researching on this, I found that Windows 7 does not support moving hosts file to the other place. You may refer to the following link to use script to copy hosts file to etc folder.
>
> http://www.techimo.com/forum/networking-internet/108391-using-hosts-file-across-network.html
>
> Important Note: Microsoft provides third-party contact information to help you find technical support. This contact information may change without notice. Microsoft does not guarantee the accuracy of this third-party contact information.

Comment: Thanks for the official response. Microsoft yet again did something brain-dead (the key is still present for no good reason). This is highly inconvenient and copying it defeats the purpose of a centralized copy. As a temporary measure, I had added a line to a batch file to copy it (which means wasting 6MB), but I guess it’s now permanent. `:-|`